# Вывод с сортировкой

Tags: сортировка, unix, shell, консоль

Вывести рекурсивно список имен и атрибутов файлов в директории, заканчивающихся на символ 'e', список отсортировать по возрастанию количества жестких ссылок, ошибки доступа не подавлять и не перенаправлять. Делал такой командой "ls -lR | sort -n -k 2 | grep ‘e$’" и всё работало, но если имя файла или директории содержит символ переноса строки и ещё некоторые символы после символа "e", то команда выводит лишь кусок имени и без атрибутов, так как обрабатывает именно строки а не имена. Как изменить команду так, чтобы лишние строки не выводились?
Список файлов в директории: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как видно на втором скрине, выводится лишь часть имени.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Многие утилиты командной строки поддерживают в качестве разделителя «строк» ноль (или произвольный символ) `sort` — не исключение.

Кроме того использование `ls -R` в скриптах — плохая практика. Обычно вместо этого применяется утилита `find`.

Как вариант, без сортировки:

```
find -name '*e' -exec ls -l '{}' \+
```

Если сортировка по количеству хардлинков критична, то можно сделать что-нибудь помудрёней:

```
find -name '*e' -exec stat --printf '%h\t%n\0' '{}' \+ | sort -z -n | cut -z -f 2- | xargs -0 ls -Uld
```

ЗЫ: Обычно в своих скриптах «для себя» (да и чего уж греха таить — не только для себя) мало-кто подзакладывается на наличие файлов с переводом строк — уж очень это обычно муторно. А к тем странным людям, что всё же намеренно создают такие файлы большинство относится, как к любителям пощеголять по улице в плаще на голое тело или к тем, кто заводится от циклических хардлинков.

**Дисклеймер**: Примеры проверялись в гнутом окружении, сверку с POSIX на наличие всех приведённых ключей я не делал.